# Ошибка при десериализации

Tags: c#, json, вконтакте

Столкнулся с ошибкой при десериализации ответа от api.vk.com.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getChatUsers?chat_id=101&v=5.74&access_token=тут мой токен";

    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    if (req != null)
    {
        HttpWebResponse res = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));

        Console.WriteLine(stream.ReadToEnd());

        var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(stream.ReadToEnd());

        Console.WriteLine(item.users[1]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
public class RootObject
{
    public List<int> users { get; set; }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам ответ от API: 
`{"response":[218803928,317010917,179681066,173431607,356408021,421702993,295920106,121375474,261654407,322744642,307578021,384790605,223522189,141711244,286562711,204691290,343742090,474494798,237102289,478504542,177436279,196611542,66950243,189052497,331084770,421534614,225194958,224984110,204442992,48511162,436569015,253920936,460621648]}`

Comment: Вы дважды вызываете `stream.ReadToEnd()`. Во второй раз поток уже пуст.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, всё работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что я два раза вызывал stream.ReadToEnd(). Решено, спасибо Alexander Petrov.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по json, название свойства в классе RootObject должно быть response, а не users.

Comment: Всё та же ошибка, разницы никакой.

Comment: @FaridJannatov А вы еще раз внимательней посмотрите... Вам дали верный ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ item было null. Изменил users на response, всё та же ошибка.

Comment: @FaridJannatov Ну я тогда не знаю в чем ваша проблема, проверил, все работает, даже вот вам [Онлайн](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kOVHrP). Заменено всего лишь одно слово и убрано лишнее.